# find a free,cluster working influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I'm going to use influxdb to store a lot of iot data from sensors.
As the last cluster version of influxdbv0.11 is not ready to use in production, and the Relay HA is too young too, is there another way to scale-out influxdb?
eg:

1. What are the maturity of **the last cluster version** of influxdb v0.11? Should I customize v0.11 or try other cost-saving way.
2. How about use **kafka infront of influxdb** to buffer data when influxdb got down?
3. How about sharding?Is there any **detailed document about sharding** in influxdb( https://influxdata.com/high-availability/)?

Any way, I just want to find a free, cluster working influxdb.

Answer (score 1):

Other than InfluxDB Relay there isn't a free way to scale out InfluxDB.

Comment: I am trying to stress the Influx Relay by writing to the server using the "Inch" tool. Of course the relay resides between the server and the clinet.  The inch tool works fine and the stress databases is created at the server but no matter how much I stress using Inch, the relay never scale. Would you please help me as in how to stress the realy and trigger it to scale out (adding more relays) . Thank you

Comment: Relay isn't used for scaling, it's used for HA.